# "URI is not hierarchial" when recursively searching for images in jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, recursion, jar, uri

I am programming a game in Java, and I have coded a system to preload all of the sprites beforehand. To do this, it recursively checks the "img" directory for every .png file, adding their paths to a list called "preloadQueue." It works perfectly fine in Eclipse, but when I export it as a jar and run it, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical
    at java.io.File.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at shipyard.Shipyard.preloadQueueDefaultImages(Shipyard.java:487)
    at shipyard.Shipyard.init(Shipyard.java:123)
    at shipyard.Shipyard.main(Shipyard.java:101)
```

It seems to be a problem with URI formatting, but after several hours of trying, I can't find a way that works. I have tried using different methods of getting a File object, as well as searched the Internet for someone else with the same problem, but neither turned up any results. All I can gather is that the URI doesn't work as a result of either A, it having to go through a jar file, or B, it referencing a directory as opposed to an actual file, however I could find solutions to neither problem.

Here is my code (starting at line 486 for reference to the command line error):

```
private void preloadQueueDefaultImages() throws URISyntaxException, UnsupportedEncodingException{
    File imgDir = new File(getClass().getResource("/img/").toURI());
    System.out.println("Image directory is: " + imgDir.getAbsolutePath());
    for(File f : getAllFilesFromDirectory(imgDir)) if(f.getName().endsWith(".png")) preloadQueue.add(f.getAbsolutePath());
}

private List<File> getAllFilesFromDirectory(File dir){
    List<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();
    for(File f : dir.listFiles()){
        if(f.isDirectory()) files.addAll(getAllFilesFromDirectory(f));
        else files.add(f);
    }
    return files;
}
```

Comment: I put my bet on path naming influence when you are running as standalone applicaton. What is the path of directory you want to run app from? I don't know how are you loading your images later on, but if you are using `ImageIO` or if you can read images from streams, than don't open images as files, but as streams by `getClass().getResourceAsStream(...)`;

Comment: I want the program to run independent of the path, so it needs to be able to work wherever I put it. Also, I am using ImageIO to _read_ the images as streams, but before I can do that I need to _identify_ the images and this is the only way I could find. Is it actually possible to get the images by opening the whole directory as a stream? If so, that would be perfect for what I'm doing. The idea is that any image I put in that directory will be automatically identified and loaded without having to list them somewhere.